# How do I configure Wildfly for URL Rewriting an Anuglar application

Tags: angular, wildfly

i have a subdirectory for my angular applications and i publish the subdirectory with this config in my standalone.xml

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                ...
                <location name="/app" handler="app" />
                ..
            </host>


<handlers>
            <...
            <file name="app" path="${jboss.home.dir}/../app"/>
```

...

so now i have to know how i can redirect this to the index.html if i want use direct link for my route.

For Apache would it look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i build a war with grunt and added then a undertow-handlers.conf